# Solve the following initial value and boundary problem: $u_{tt} -c^{2}u_{xx} = 0$, $0<x<T$, $t>0$ with $u(0,t) = a(t)$, $u(L,t) = b(t)$, $t \geq 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Solve the following initial value and boundary problem.

$u_{tt} -c^{2}u_{xx} = 0$, $0<x<T$, $t>0$

$u(x,0) = \varphi(x)$, $u_{t}(x,0) = \psi(x)$, $0 \leq x \leq L$

$u(0,t) = a(t)$, $u(L,t) = b(t)$, $t \geq 0$

This problem models the motion of a vibrating string with the initial position given by $\varphi$ and initial velocity given by $\psi$, with free ends whose motion is controlled by functions $a$ at the left end and $b$ at the right end.

I solved this problem in the case in which the vibrating string is fixed at the ends, that is, when $u(0,t) = 0$ and $u(L,t) = 0$. In this case, I obtain the solution in terms of Fourier series and is given by

$$u(x,t) = \left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_{n}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi ct}{L}\right) + b_{n}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi ct}{L}\right)}\right]\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$
Where the Fourier coefficients are given by $$a_{n} = \frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}{\varphi(\epsilon)\sin \left(\frac{n\pi \epsilon}{L} \right)}d\epsilon$$ and $$b_{n} = \frac{2}{n\pi c}\int_{0}^{L}{\psi(\epsilon)\sin \left(\frac{n\pi \epsilon}{L} \right)}d\epsilon$$

However, in the general case, when $u(0,t) = a(t)$ y $u(L,t) = b(t)$ I have not been able to find a solution yet.
How can I do this?
I need some help!

Comment: You need to make the boundary conditions homogeneous by introducing a substitution $v = u - \tilde{u}$ such that $\tilde{u}(0,t) = a(t), \tilde{u}(L,t) = b(t)$ so that $v(0,t) = u(0,t) - \tilde{u}(0,t) = a(t) - a(t) = 0$, similarly for $v(L,t)$.

Comment: @mattos You are using the transformation $\bar{u} = u-v$. Then, by the superposition principle, $\bar{u}$ should solve the following homogeneous Cauchy problem. $\bar{u}_{tt} -\bar{u}_{xx} = 0$,$\bar{u}( x,0)= \varphi( x)-v(x,0)$, $\bar{u}_{t}( x,0) = \psi( x) - v_{t}( x,0)$ , $\bar{u}( 0,t) = a( t) - v( t)$, $bar{u}(L,t) = b( x) - v( t)$. I am right?. Now, In your substitution, who is v? On the other hand, why do you say that $\bar{u}(0, t) = a (x)$ and $\bar{u}(L, t) = b (x)$?

Comment: Your not constructing the PDE in $\tilde{u}$, $\tilde{u}$ is a function _you need to determine explicitly_. You're constructing it in $v$. You should get \begin{align} v_{tt} &= c^{2} v_{xx} + \text{terms in } \tilde{u}\\ v(x,0) &= \varphi - \tilde{u}(x,0) \\ v_{t}(x,0) &= \psi - \tilde{u}(x,0) \\ v(0,t) &= a(t) - a(t) = 0 \\ v(L,t) &= b(t) - b(t) = 0 \end{align} See section 7.1 [here](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~grigoryan/124B/lecs/lec7.pdf) for more.